# Where has Karn run off to?

Tags: darksiders-2

I'm trying to complete the Shaman's quest for a Talisman in Darksiders 2, but after collecting both the stalker's bone and the mordant dew, the next step in the quest is to find and speak to Karn again... but I can't find him!

He wasn't outside the Drenchfort, like he had waited outside the Cauldron, and he doesn't seem to be showing up on my map either.

Where is that pup?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He is in the lost temple.Keep doing the main quest and you will eventually meet him

Answer (score 7):

Although you already have the answer: Making that quest the current one will show you Karn's position on the map. This works for all quests. Select the quest in your quest log and make it the active one (for example, on PS3 it is the square button).

Comment: Very helpful! +1 for you!